# Apache mod_rewrite - redirect all traffic to another domain, except in 5 folders

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, mod-rewrite

We are gradually moving a clients site to a new system & domain name.
In the meantime we need both sites live - but sharing bits of the same domain.

I have now pointed the primary domain to the new server - www.newserver.org

On this server I need Apache to redirect any requests not in a list of allowable folders back to the old server - now living on: www.oldserver.org (preserving the path after the domain).

I also need the new server to be accessible without redirecting when accessed via it's IP address.

My best attempt at the apache configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newserver.org$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://www.oldserver.org/$1  [NC,R=301,L]
```

Can anyone assist with the right RewriteCond & ordering?
At the moment all requests - even to the specified folders are redirecting.

Comment: 301 redirects will be cached by your browser.  You really want a 302 here.